# Sent email name

Tags: gmail, outlook.com

When I send an email from my hotmail account the receiver of the email will see the name of the sender as first_name second_name (Joe Carpenter).
Now for my gmail account I want to do the same thing but I do not know how my emails just show the whole email address as the sender name.
can anybody help me on that?

Comment: See also: [Does my name get sent along with my email?](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/12330)

Answer (score 1):

Do the following:

1. Log in to your Gmail account
2. Click on the Gear in the upper-right corner
3. Click 'Settings'
4. Click on the 'Accounts' heading
5. Under the "Send mail as" section, click the 'edit info' link on the right side
6. Enter the name you want to display (You can even change the reply-to address)
7. Profit!

Comment: I tried it yesterday not working

Comment: Did you save the change?  I can't imagine how it wouldn't work...  Wait, are you using the web interface to send the e-mails, or are you using a different program, like Outlook, Thunderbird, K-9, etc?

Comment: the web interface